How to use RequireComponent(typeof(Collider) ? getting message error
I want to add an collider automatically to the gameobject with the script.
When trying to attach the script to any gameobject in the hierarchy it's showing this error message:

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider))]
public class InteractableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum InteractableMode
    {
        Description,
        Action
    }

    [Header("Interaction Settings")]
    public InteractableMode interactableMode = InteractableMode.Description;
    public float interactionDistance = 5f;
    [TextArea(1, 10)]
    public string description = "";

    private IKControl ikControl;

    private void Start()
    {
        ikControl = FindObjectOfType<IKControl>();
        if (ikControl != null)
        {
            ikControl.lookObjects.Add(transform);
        }
    }

    public bool IsAction()
    {
        return interactableMode == InteractableMode.Action;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (ikControl != null && ikControl.lookObjects.Contains(transform))
        {
            ikControl.lookObjects.Remove(transform);
        }
    }
}


as it says, you cant just "add a collider" it has to be a shape, pick a shape....

yeah just using the generic Collider here is tricky ... how should the editor know which one you would like to be added exactly? This only makes sense if you already have a specific collider and want to prevent that it can be removed ...

you need to specify what collider you want to use. so use [RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider))] for example instead of just [RequireComponent(typeof(Collider))]
